# Why does configure take variables as arguments?

Tags: configure, autotools

Is `VAR=value ./configure` the same as `./configure VAR=value`?

In the first case, the shell sets the environment variable and in the second the configure script takes the string `'VAR=value'` as an argument, and then presumably sets the variable. I wonder if configure does anything else with the variable (maybe ignore or filter some values), and why it takes variables as arguments in the first place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case

```
VAR=value ./configure
```

the behavior depends on your current shell, while in this

```
./configure VAR=value
```

the behavior depends on the configure-script.  Some of the developers prefer the latter because they would like to choose whether to set variables within the script, rather than have someone magically set the script's variables from outside.

In practice, there is little difference because

- most people doing configuration are running from a POSIX shell, where the former behavior "just works", and
- most configure scripts do not unset existing environment variables, and
- the conventional environment variables (outside automake) have long-established usage

For instance, the bash configure script's `--help` message shows this:

```
Some influential environment variables:
  DEBUGGER_START_FILE
              location of bash debugger initialization file
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    C/C++/Objective C preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  YACC        The `Yet Another C Compiler' implementation to use. Defaults to
              the first program found out of: `bison -y', `byacc', `yacc'.
  YFLAGS      The list of arguments that will be passed by default to $YACC.
              This script will default YFLAGS to the empty string to avoid a
              default value of `-d' given by some make applications.
```

and in each case, either way of setting the variable *works*.

But keep in mind the developer's preferences, in case someone decides to "improve" things.

Further reading:

- [Passing environment variables to autoconf's `./configure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848154/passing-environment-variables-to-autoconfs-configure)
  which states that the latter (VAR=value) is needed to put the value into `config.status`
- [3.3. Environment Variables as Arguments](https://autotools.io/autoconf/arguments.html)
  discusses `AC_ARG_VAL`, from the viewpoint of automake (and expresses developer's preferences):

> The `AC_ARG_VAR` macro is used to declare a particular (environment) variable as an argument for the script, giving it a description and a particular use. While this feature has been *added relatively recently in the history of autoconf*, it is really important. Reflecting its more recent presence, the macro does not need the `AS_HELP_STRING` helper, and only takes two parameters: the name of the variable and the string printed during ./configure --help:
>
> `AC_ARG_VAR(var-name, help-string)`

and continues with a comment about longstanding practice:

> By default, configure picks up the variables from the environment like any other sh script. Most of those are ignored. Those that are not should be declared through this macro. This way they are marked as a precious variable.
>
> A variable marked as precious gets *replaced in the Makefile.in* without having to call an explicit `AC_SUBST`, but that's not the most important part of the definition. What is important is that the variable is cached.

- [7.2 Setting Output Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html) (autoconf documentation) 
  describes `AC_ARG_VAR`, again expressing developer's preferences.:

  > The value of variable when configure was launched is saved in the cache, including if it was not specified on the command line but via the environment. Indeed, while configure can notice the definition of CC in ‘./configure CC=bizarre-cc’, it is impossible to notice it in ‘CC=bizarre-cc ./configure’, which, unfortunately, is what most users do.

Comment: You may also want to describe how `env VAR=value ./configure` relates to `VAR=value ./configure`